# Plant ID Needed - making my dog sick!

Tags: identification, flowers, flowering, toxicity, outdoor

Does anyone know what kind of plant this is in the photos?
My dog keeps eating the leaves, and it makes him sick.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also note that Lantana can grow pretty rapidly depending on the location and can be a nuisance if it's unwanted.  We have some that grows in with our bushes and although its very pretty, I consider it a weed because of how it grows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is lantana. [ASPCA Website](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/toxic-and-non-toxic-plants/lantana) says:

"Lantana

Additional Common Names: Shrub Verbena, Yellow Sage, Red Sage

Scientific Name: Lantana camara

Family: Verbenaceae

Toxicity: Toxic to Dogs, Toxic to Cats, Toxic to Horses

Toxic Principles: Pentacyclic triterpenoids

Clinical Signs: Vomiting, diarrhea, labored breathing, weakness. Liver failure - more common in livestock."

Comment: Yup, and really popular for people who like to attract butterflies

Comment: And deer love to eat it, mostly the blooms and buds. Butterflys also love it , they fly al around looking for blooms the deer didn't get .

Answer (score 1):

As above, this is Lantana, which is a decorative shrub originally from tropical Africa and America. In Australia, at least, it's [classified](https://weeds.dpi.nsw.gov.au/Weeds/Details/78) as a Weed of National Significance (one of 32), so it's illegal to sell and it generally should be eliminated where possible. I have spent many weeks removing Lantana from my aunt's outback property; it's a real nuisance.

Poisoning from Lantana can be quite serious, particularly if the berries are eaten, and I'd recommend taking your dog to a vet. There's extensive information [here](https://wagwalking.com/condition/lantana-poisoning).